# Azure mobile: Client-directed login operation error (Facebook)

Tags: facebook, azure

I am trying to use "Client-directed login operation" to authorize users with Facebook account on my azure-mobile service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj710106.aspx)

I downloaded and configured iOS Facebook SDK for the project;

Here is the code for user login:

```
NSArray* permissions = @[@"email, user_about_me, basic_info"];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession* session, FBSessionState status, NSError* error) {
     if (!error) {
          [_msClient loginWithProvider:provider
                                 token:@{@"access_token" : [[session accessTokenData] accessToken]}
                            completion:^(MSUser* user, NSError* error) {
               NSLog(@"%@", error); 
          }];
     }
}];
```

This code returns error:

```
Error Domain=com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorDomain Code=-1302 "Error: The Facebook Graph API access token authorization request failed with HTTP status code 400" UserInfo=0x1768ba80 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error: The Facebook Graph API access token authorization request failed with HTTP status code 400}
```

I can confirm, that

```
NSString* access_token = [[session accessTokenData] accessToken];
```

returns a valid access token, because it works here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me without any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem and I can confirm that the error returned by Azure Mobile Service is most unhelpful. I eventually read up about what's happening under the hood here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending

Then I tried to acquire the long-lived token by invoking a GET request manually (https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}) and here I finally got the real error message. In my case it turned out to be "The request is invalid because the app is configured as a desktop app" and simply flipping a switch in the Facebook app configuration fixed it.

In your case it might be a different error message, but I suggest you take this approach and see where it takes you.

Answer (score 0):

This is old now but just had the same issue. Check that you don't have the "Is Your App Secret Embedded" switched on in. I had it on because I thought the ZUMO SDK would have it somewhere, but I guess it just lives on the cloud in your MS identity configuration.